# SSO working functionality in browser

Tags: pingfederate

i have some doubts on the SSO functionalities in different browsers,

-> if i enter my SSO application URL in IE browser it is automatically taking my windows credentials and it is allowing me to access the applications without re-authenticating.
-> same URL i have tried in Mozilla and Google Chrome browsers but it is asking for credentials. its weird for me by not taking the windows credentials.

could you please help me with this, do i have to change any settings in mozilla and chrome browsers to access the SSO application without asking credentials.

Note: It is from both the internal network and outside network.

Thanks,
Gowthaman. p

Comment: To enable SSO, you need to run Chrome with an extra command line parameter:                                                                            chrome.exe --auth-server-whitelist="*example.com"   and for FF see this link http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/\

Answer (score 2):

Ping Identity has two URLs that explain the settings required...

IE/Firefox:
https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PFIWA31/Step+Five+--+Configure+User+Browsers

Chrome:
https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA3400000008RWWCA2

Though, generally, if IE is working, then so will Chrome (on Windows), since it uses the same configuration. If you have the PingFed Server in your "Trusted" sites, remove it.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Could you please share the link whcih has resolution for this same issue ? Today even I tried logging into pingfederate with chrome and it took my Pfizer credentials automatically.